# No DaggerComponents Generated

Tags: android, dagger

**Problem:**

I am not seeing any Dagger-generated `Components` classes. I have performed `clean`, `rebuild`, `make project` but still don't get them. I am not using the `com.neenbedankt.android-apt` plugin as `Gradle 2.2.2` doesn't need it.

**Using**:

```
Android Studio Version: 2.2.2
Gradle Plugin Version: 2.2.2
Gradle Wrapper: 2.14.1
```

**Dagger:**

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.7'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.7'
```

**Application:**

```
public class EventsApplication extends Application
{
    private AuthenticationComponent authenticationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        initDaggerComponents();
    }

    private void initDaggerComponents()
    {
        // I'm suppose to use Dagger generated Components here but there aren't any created.
    }

    public AuthenticationComponent getAuthenticationComponent()
    {
        return authenticationComponent;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationModule:**

```
@Module
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ApplicationModule
{
    private final EventsApplication application;

    public ApplicationModule(final EventsApplication application)
    {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ForApplication
    Context provideApplicationContext()
    {
        return application;
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationModule:**

```
@Module
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class AuthenticationModule
{
    @Provides
    MSAAuthAndroidAdapter provideAuthenticationAdapter(final EventsApplication eventsApplication)
    {
        return new MSAAuthAndroidAdapter(eventsApplication)
        {
            @Override
            public String getClientId()
            {
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public String[] getScopes()
            {
                return new String[]{};
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationComponent:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Component(modules = {AuthenticationModule.class})
public interface AuthenticationComponent
{
    void inject(final SignInActivity activity);
}
```

Comment: Where is your code trying to use the `DaggerAuthenticationComponent`?

Comment: @JaredBurrows That's the point, it's not generated. I have stated this in the `initDaggerComponents()` method within the **Application** class.

Comment: How do you know it's not generated? Did you check the `build/generated/source` folder?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I can see a bunch of Factory classes generated but no `DaggerComponents`.

Comment: @Subby Do you have any compiler output from Dagger (via javac) that you can paste in?